# The request is missing when the page jumped

Tags: javascript, promise, request, fetch

```
fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: data, mode: 'cors' }).then(
    () => Promise.resolve(success),
    () => Promise.reject(error),
);
```

I have a page, the page has a jump button, when I click this button my page was jumped to another page, by `location.href` or `window.open ()`.

But I would like to sending a request when the jump button is clicked, through the above `fetch` function.

Now, the problem is the page jumps too fast, the request is failed. When I set a long delay the jump is success, there is better way to handle it.

Forgive me，My English is not good, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1:

Although your XHR request may takes long time to execute, you can get `readyState` for that request to take advantage of it.

[readyState](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp) number meanings:

- 0:   UNSENT  open() has not been called yet.
- 1:   OPENED  send() has been called.
- 2:   HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
- 3:   LOADING Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
- 4:   DONE    The operation is complete.

Normally it's already fine to let go and move to next page with `readyState >= 2`. Since most server start to process data at this point, and will not do any detection to stop even if you cancel request.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/');
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  console.log(xhr.readyState);
  if (xhr.readyState>=2) window.location.href = 'http://targeturl';
};
xhr.send();
```

### Method 2:

This is another way that works via server delegation call.

```
var url = 'http://ip:port/uri?delegation=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com';

fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: data, mode: 'cors' }).then(
    () => {
       window.location.href = 'http://targeturl';
    },
    () => Promise.reject(error),
);
```

Then your server parse `delegation` part and do request ex: in another thread, and return ASAP, so the main page won't get blocks.

Comment: I know this method, but the request time may be very long or the request failed, but I would like to ensure that the success rate of redirect to another page is 100% and as fast as possible.

Comment: do you have control of requesting server?

Comment: I can't control the server

Comment: added method 3 - to replace old method 1 (which not works for you)

Answer (score 1):

If you care more about the redirection than the request being successful, you can use `Promise.race()` to induce a timeout:

```
// Helper that creates a Promise that resolves after n milliseconds
const delay = n => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, n));

Promise.race([fetch(url), delay(1000)])
  .then(() => redirectElsewhere())
  .catch(() => {/* handle error */});
```

`Promise.race()` takes an iterable of Promises, and resolves immediately when the first of them resolves (or rejects when the first rejects).

The effect this will give you is that you'll redirect when the request Promise resolves, or after 1000ms, whichever comes first.